# Handling duplicates in Twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I have this code in my Twig template:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<ul>
    <li>{{ entity.getName }} | <a href="{{ path('detail_group_edit', { 'detail_group_id': entity.getId }) }}">Editar</a> - <a href="{{ path('detail_group_delete', { 'detail_group_id': entity.getId }) }}">Eliminar</a>
            {{ render(controller('ProductBundle:DetailGroup:index', { 'parent_id': entity.getId })) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

<dl class="sub-nav">
    <dd><a href="#" id="detail_group_create">Add new</a></dd>
</dl>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#detail_group_create").click(function() {
            loadCenterLayout(Routing.generate('detail_group_new'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Because I'm calling this `{{ render(controller('ProductBundle:DetailGroup:index', { 'parent_id': entity.getId })) }}` I get the `Add new` link twice. I don't want to create a new function to handle the same, how did yours deal with this? Any tips or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have index with dynamic center part of the layout. You either have to have:

- separate controller functions or
- single controller function but some `GET`/`POST` parameter and big `IF`/`ELSE` branching.

In second case you must not rely on `@Template` annotation (in case you use them) but rather on manually calling appropriate template render based on which branch you're in.

Did I get your issue right?

Comment: Yes you go it, I'll handle as you suggest